# how to pass glm control argument for earth using caret (maxit)

Tags: r, r-caret, glm, spline

when fitting `earth` for a `glm` model, one can pass arguments to the `glm` call. For example:

```
mars_fit <- earth(formula = response ~ x1 + x2, data = sim_dat,
                      glm = list(family=binomial, control = list(maxit = 50)))
```

Using `caret` looks like

```
fit_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
mars_grid <- expand.grid(degree=1:2, nprune=2:10)
mars_fit <- train(factor(response)~x1+x2, method='earth', trControl = fit_control, 
                  data=sim_dat, tuneGrid=mars_grid, 
                  glm = list(control = list(maxit = 50)))
```

but the `glm` list is not passed. Any advice?

Edit 1:
Reading https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/554 `caret`'s author says it is either caught in the `...` or it should be passed in the tuning grid. when passed through the tuning grid, since `glm` is a list, `train` complains that `degree` and `nprune` do not belong to the method, which is not true.
Edit 2:
Opened https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/1018

Comment: maybe someone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is solved in this commit:
https://github.com/topepo/caret/commit/2ce2cf4c5889791b7dbca5d8896fcc6dc0d0bcfc